# Store with MixedCollection data

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, store, extjs4.1

Is it possible to do this process in ExtJS 4.1.x ?

```
var myMixedCollection = myStore.queryBy(...);
var anotherStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { data: myMixedCollection, ... });
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', { store: anotherStore, ... });
```

Because my grid displays nothing or just one empty line.
When I log my `myMixedCollection` there is no problem all data are here but when I open my `anotherStore` with Firebug i can see there is only one empty line in my data store.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myMixedCollection` will be a collection of records (model instances) and as long as the new store hast the same model set this will work! So the answer is **Yes**

Well, for sure you need to call **[getRange()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection-method-getRange)** on the `myMixedCollection` instance

Here is a working example

```
 // Set up a model to use in our Store
 Ext.define('Simpson', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [
         {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'email', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'phone', type: 'string'}
     ]
 });

var s1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model:'Simpson',
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

var mixed = s1.queryBy(function(rec){
     if(rec.data.name == 'Lisa')
         return true;
});

var s1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model:'Simpson',
    storeId:'simpsonsStore2',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: mixed.getRange(),
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore2'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

and the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/6/)**

Comment: Yes it works, I forget to use the getRange() method. Thx sra.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

Try this:

```
//this is the model we will be using in the store
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string', mapping: 'phoneNumber'}
    ]
});

var data = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
data.add('key1', {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ed Spencer',
    phoneNumber: '555 1234'
});
data.add('key2', {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Abe Elias',
    phoneNumber: '666 1234'
});

//note how we set the 'root' in the reader to match the data structure above
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'User',
    data : data.items,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    }
});

store.each(function(record){
    console.log(record.get("name"));
});
```

​You can see it woking on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lontivero/Lf9yv/1/

Comment: Lol, so well here is the proof then ;-) +1 for all the same answer.  Dunno if your repurtation is already enough, but you can see the upvote/downvote rate if you tip on the score. Yours is now 1/1 ;) last but not least, no I didn't.

Comment: awww, -1 trolls are about again? here is a +1 to make them go away :)